# What is causing this memory leak?

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks

Memory leakage happened. What's wrong with the code?

```
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf=NULL;

static void alarm_func()  
{  
   siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);  
}  
static struct hostent *timeGethostbyname(const char *domain, int timeout)  
{  
    struct hostent *ipHostent = NULL;  
    jmpbuf=malloc(sizeof(sigjmp_buf));
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_func);  
    if(sigsetjmp(jmpbuf, 1) != 0)  
    {  
        alarm(0);
        signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);  
        return NULL;  
    }  
    alarm(timeout);//setting alarm  
    ipHostent = gethostbyname(domain);  
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);  
    return ipHostent;  
}
```

something wrong in function `timeGethostbyname`.
 if I call the function `timeGethostbyname` many times.Memory leakage will be happened.
 EX:

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv ){
        char *servers="www.aaa.bbb.tt";
        struct hostent *h;
        while(1){
            h=timeGethostbyname(servers, 2);
        }

        return(0);

    }
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question so that the line triggering the memory leak is removed. That makes the whole question pointless and the answers are confusing (since they refer to a line of code which isn't thre).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't deallocate memory, dynamically allocated by malloc `jmpbuf=malloc(sizeof(sigjmp_buf));` 
Add `free(jmpbuf)`  before `return ipHostent;`  from function `*timeGethostbyname`.

notice you code runs a loop to call a function where memory allocated, and you are continuously allocating memory without `free()`.

Remember in C, we don't have garbage collector that automatically manage memory (free) when object goes out-of scope---In C you have to explicitly deallocated memory. using `free()` function. So even you variable `jmpbuf` local to function `timeGethostbyname()` you need to deallocate/free memory before return, otherwise it will remain allocated to your process (an as you loss the address of the memory in new function call  --memory leak).

Besides memory leak, you must be getting an error/warning in your code because you are declaring  `jmpbuf`  as value variable of `static sigjmp_buf` but not pointer. Either declare its as `static sigjmp_buf*` type or you don't even need allocate memory for it.

Comment: sorry the coed is not correct.I have updated the correct version. I don't use malloc

Comment: @user2621581 if you doubts are not clear let me know in comments, no problem.. As I notice revision history of your question, I had deleted `malloc()` statement that was more buggy code, because your were using `jumpbuf`  in stead address as I have suggested, your code will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first make `static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf=NULL;` to `static sigjmp_buf *jmpbuf=NULL;`

And then `free` whatever you allocated by `malloc` once you have done with the allocated memory.

In this case I do not think you need to `malloc` the `sigjmp_buf` if you do  `sigjmp_buf jmpbuf=NULL;` and use the memory allocated in global scope (data area), instead of heap.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to allocate memory for jmpbuf, since is it already allocated by following declaration and definition:

```
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf=NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not freeing the memory allocated by malloc. All allocations by malloc should be freed after use, otherwise you will get a memory leak.